# Styling navigation in swiper

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, swiper.js

hello i want a style like this navigation but i can't seem to style it correctly get it done, i will post below the picture that i need
as i tried to make it absolute and position it outside of this element but it doesn't work. i know there are some easy fixed somewhere but i can't seem to find i am new to this

[image: This is how it must be]

```
  const renderSwiper = (
    <>
      <Swiper
        spaceBetween={0}
        slidesPerView={1}
        modules={[Navigation]}
        navigation={{
          nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
          prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        }}
        breakpoints={{
          350: { slidesPerView: 1 },
          420: { slidesPerView: 2 },
          640: { slidesPerView: 3 },
          820: { slidesPerView: 4 },
          1000: { slidesPerView: 5 },
        }}
      >
        {renderSlides}
        <div className="swiper-button-next rounded-full bg-gray-500 after:absolute after:-right-0"></div>
        <div className="swiper-button-prev rounded-full bg-gray-500 after:absolute after:right-0"></div>
      </Swiper>

    </>
  );

  return <div className="flex max-w-[80%] relative">{renderSwiper}</div>;
```

here is where i am so far at,
any help would be greatly appreciated.